# Common ToolBar in UWP c++

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I am attempting to make a multipage app and would like to use a common navigation toolbar across all pages.  The page includes:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button />
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

In App.xaml I can define the AppBar that goes into the Page.TopAppBar:

```
   <Application.Resources>
    <AppBar x:Key="CommonAppBar" x:Name="AppBarCommon">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button />
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Application.Resources>
```

But how can I use this AppBar defination in the Page xaml?

Comment: There is no standard C++ framework for UWP that has XAML support. Would you rather tag this question using the [tag:c++-cx] tag?

Comment: The project template I'm using is described as: "A project for a single Universal Windows Platform app that has no predefined controls or layout".  It's under Visual c++ -> Windows -> Universal->Blank App (Universal Windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) control on one page and show another your pages inside that frame. Then you can add an AppBar to this page.

By the way, the [`AppBarButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton) is the button that is used inside an AppBar, not StackPanel and Buttons (your approach will still work, but if you expect the same behaviour and look as in other UWP apps, it's easier to use AppBarButtons).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have a prototype that changes pages using Frame already.  The question is "can I reuse the AppBar?"  And of course the AppBar Code.

Comment: You don't have to reuse it if you have only one instance of it on the page with the frame..

Comment: This will be a multiple page app.  I'm trying to not have to duplicate the code.

Comment: You don't have to have duplicate code, there will be one AppBar on the main page and another pages will be shown in the frame so you don't have to create AppBars on the pages.